# Call Activator for constructor with params parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, activator

I am trying to instantiate a type using `Activator`'s reflection magic. Unfortunately the type I want to instantiate has a `params` parameter of type `object`. See this extract:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name, params object[] arguments)
    {
    }
}
```

And the instantiation goes here:

```
public static class Bar
{
    public static object Create(params object[] arguments)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo), "foo", arguments);
    }
}
```

Now, this effectively results in a constructor call with the signature

```
new Foo(string, object[])
```

because `object[]` is also `object`.

What I actually want is:

```
new Foo(string, object, object, object, ...)
```

Is this even possible with Activator? Or how do I instantiate a type with such a parameter type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is a purely-compile-time syntactic sugar.
The runtime, including the parameter binding used by reflection, ignores it.

You need to pass a normal array, just like a non-`params` parameter.

In your case, it sounds like you're trying to not call the `params` overload.

You need to build a single (flattened) array containing all of the parameters you want to pass:

```
object[] args = new object[arguments.Length + 1];
args[0] = "foo";
arguments.CopyTo(args, 1);
```

Comment: All this syntactic sugar makes me diabetic.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters like this:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(Foo),
    new object[] { "foo" }.Concat(arguments).ToArray());
```